# Can std::find function use for our own classes?

Tags: c++

I have set of classes. Each class is inherited from another class. The relationship is as follows. (I am just posting how one class inherited from another class, just to get idea for all of you)

```
class LineNumberList : public MyVector <LineNumber > //top class
class MyVector : public std::vector <Type>
class LineNumber : public ElementNumber 

class ElementNumber {                 //this is the base class
        protected:
    int number;
        public:
    ElementNumber(int p){number=p;}
         // some more codes // 
}
```

Now, I want to implement a function which can be used to `find` elements inside my topclass i.e. `LineNumberList`. I tried with standard `find` function, but it doesn’t work. Can anyone help me to implement similar find function for my case, it is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the actual code? This can't possibly be what you have. What's the definition of `LineNumber`, `MyVector`, `Type`, and `LineNumberList`? And why are you deriving from `std::vector` since composition seems to be the much better option here? And I can't help but to think that you're way over-designing this. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried std::find_if(). Also it's quite weired to derive from vector instead using it's as a member variable...

Comment: You almost certainly do *not* want to do this. `vector` isn't designed or intended to use as a base class, and using it that way is asking for trouble.

Comment: Be wary of inheriting from classes that weren't expressly designed to be superclasses (i.e., std::vector). It has a non-virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I tried with standard find function, but it doesn’t work."  Works for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class ElementNumber {
  protected:
    int number;
  public:
    ElementNumber(int p) :number(p) {}
    bool operator==(const ElementNumber&e) { return number == e.number; }
};
class LineNumber : public ElementNumber {
  public:
    LineNumber(int p) : ElementNumber(p) {}
};
template <class Type>
class MyVector : public std::vector<Type> {
};
class LineNumberList : public MyVector<LineNumber> {
};

// EDIT: add local implementation of std::find
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator myfind ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value )
{
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/
  for ( ;first!=last; first++) if ( *first==value ) break;
  return first;
}

int main() {
  LineNumberList ll;
  LineNumber l(7);
  ll.push_back(l);
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !(std::find(ll.begin(), ll.end(), l) == ll.end()) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << !(::myfind(ll.begin(), ll.end(), l) == ll.end()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @ rob, thank you for your response. but, i would like to learn how can i implemente std::find for our own classes instead of calling that function. any possibility to do this sir?

Comment: @g_niro : "*instead of calling that function*" Instead of calling _what_ function? He directly demonstrates calling `std::find` with your class types.

Comment: @g_niro, why do you not want to call `std::find`? (Seriously though, don't use inheritance like this, and avoid inheritance in C++ altogether unless you really know what you are doing. Templates and object composition almost always present a better alternative.)

Comment: @g_niro - I must have misunderstood your question. If you want to implement std::find on your own, see my edit.